# Why does Stata calculate different sums depending on aggregation of variables?

Tags: stata

I noticed that Stata estimates slightly different sums depending on the level of aggregation of the summands.

To use an example, I have 4 variables (Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4).

```
Var1        Var2        Var3        Var4
420966      10804428    21982560    1055822272
207381      20133238    69127000    580531008
217297.6    7946694.5   23631250    554597952
327553.2    7505444     10898800    261170592
119776.4    715082.75   607820.3125 414926752
3758613     2533234.5   225734784   88380432
```

First, I estimate the sum of all 4 variables:

```
gen sumVars1234 = Var1 + Var2 + Var3 + Var4 
   // this calculates the same sum as `egen rowtotal`
```

Then I estimate the sum of Vars 1 and 2, and Vars 3 and 4, separately:

```
gen sumVars12 = Var1 + Var2 
gen sumVars34 = Var3 + Var4
```

When I add together `sumVars12` and `sumVars34`, this generates `sumVars12_34`:

```
gen sumVars12_34 = sumVars12 + sumVars34
gen dif = sumVars12_34 - sumVars1234    // I calculate difference between both sums
```

However, `sumVars12_34` does NOT equal `sumVars1234` and I don't understand why.

```
sumVars12   sumVars34   sumVars12_34    sumVars1234     dif
11225394    1077804800  1089030144      1089030272      -128
20340618    649657984   669998592       669998656       -64
8163992     578229184   586393152       586393216       -64
7832997     272069376   279902368       279902400       -32
834859.125  415534560   416369408       416369440       -32
6291848     314115200   320407040       320407072       -32
```

I know these differences are very small, and I'm sure there's a simple explanation, but I'm not sure what it is! Any insight would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are using float storage type by default. To hold very large integers exactly you need long or double type. Note that the differences are powers of 2, a tell-tale sign of a precision problem.

Comment: I'd check against the original. It is possible that data were rounded on input too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely due to "mixed math" (integers and real floating point type variables).  You have digit precision in the input data which also contains Integers, so it's probably due to rounding.  I would replicate the calculations in Excel, but only if .0 was added to your whole integers.  In Excel, as you may know, you can select all the data in a range of cells, right-click, then select Format Cells-->Number, and specify 1 for Decimal Places.  And then do your summing.

Comment: Is there a way to generate sums in Stata without rounding? Thanks!

Comment: As Nick Cox alluded to above, if you ensure that your variables with large integers are stored as type `long` or `double` then the rounding shouldn't be an issue. The method you use for ensuring the variables are the correct type depends on how you imported data into Stata (e.g. `import excel` or `import delimited`). See the help files for each of those commands for details on how to specify the variable type when importing data.